# How do I skip the parent iteration step when the step on a nested iteration skips normally?

Tags: ruby, loops, iterator

I have some nested iterators that look like this:

```
line_count = 1
if commit.body.lines.each do |line|
  unless @diff_line_nums.include? line_count
     puts line
  else
     filtered_diffs.each do |diff|
         diff.body.lines.each do |line|
             puts line
         end
     end
   end
  line_count += 1
end
```

Which in simple terms, this is what happens in my current version:

```
a      line_count = 1
b      line_count = 2
c -    line_count = 3
   1
   2
   3
d      line_count = 4
e -    line_count = 5
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
f      line_count = 6
g      line_count = 7
h      line_count = 8
i      line_count = 9
j      line_count = 10
```

However, what I want to happen is:

```
a      line_count = 1
b      line_count = 2
c -    line_count = 3
   1
   2
   3
   4
h      line_count = 8
i      line_count = 9
j -    line_count = 10
   1
   2
   3
n     line_count = 14
o     line_count = 15
p     line_count = 16
```

Aka....while it is iterating in the outer block, once it goes into an inner iteration and processes each item successfully, on each successful iteration of the inner it should auto-increment the outer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a second variable to hold an additional counter. Something like this:

```
line_count = 1
shifted_line_count = 0

if commit.body.lines.each do |line|
  unless @diff_line_nums.include? line_count
     puts line + shifted_line_count
  else
     filtered_diffs.each do |diff|
         diff.body.lines.each do |line|
             shifted_line_count += 1
             puts line
         end
     end
   end
  line_count += 1
end
```

Comment: I think you are getting there, but all my `line_count` does is track the line number that is currently being evaluated. It doesn't actually modify the line actually being evaluated. So assuming we do use this new counter, how would I modify the actual iterator (aka `commit.body.lines.each`) to skip to the `shifted_line_count` once we come out of that nested iterator?

Comment: I've assumed here that you don't want to modify `line_count`. If you do, why not increment it directly in the inner loop? Then you don't need a secondary variable.

Comment: No man. Remember that `line_count` is literally just a counter, it doesn't actually affect the local object in that iteration. It just tracks it. I have updated the question to show what I really want to do. In other words, if the nested iteration kicks in when the outer iteration is at `c`, and the nested collection has 3 objects, then by the time the nested iteration completes 3 steps later, the outer iteration should be at `g`, rather than at `d` (which would be 1 step up, rather than 4 steps up). So how do I modify the outer iteration to skip `N` places ahead....